# Manejo correcto de claves y configuraciones Django

Tags: django, github

tengo una app en Django dentro de la cual manejo temas como
correo para envios de email, tambien otras claves y configuraciones necesarias, todo esto lo tengo dentro de **settings.py** funciona bien.

El problema surgue al subir mi proyecto a **GitHub** al ser publico(gratuito) se expone estos datos sencibles como claves de correos entre otros.

Como puedo manejar de manera eficiente este tema dado que con github subo y bajo cambios tanto a local como al servidor en produccion que solo tengo acceso por consola.

Ejemplo de configuración en settings.py:

```
ADMINS = (
  ('Diego Avila', 'diego.avila@domain.com'),
)
# CONFIGURAR PARAMETROS EMAIL
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'mail.domain.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'diego.avila@domain.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'q1w2e3r4t5'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
COPIA_EMAIL = 'diego.avila@domain.com'

"""
Parametros SRI:
    AMBIENTE_SRI 1/2:
        1 -> PRUEBAS 
        2 -> PRODUCCION
    TIEMPO_ESPERA:
        30.0 -> 30 Segundos
        10.0 -> 10 Segundos
        05.0 -> 5 Segundos
        03.0 -> 3 Segundos
"""

TIEMPO_ESPERA = 5.5
AMBIENTE_SRI = 1
TIPO_EMISION = 1 #normal
CODIGO_FACTURA = '01'
CODIGO_CR = '07'
DIGITOS_COMPLEMENTARIOS = '19903712'
IESS_EMPLEADO = 9.45
IESS_EMPLEADOR = 11.15
PW_FIRMAELECTRONICA = '123v1792'
```

este es un ejemplo de datos que deseo manejar en Django sin exponerlos en Github, gracias por su ayuda..!!

Comment: Puedes usar bitbucket que te deja crear unos cuantos repositorios privados. Pero la solución que se da normalmente es directamente no subir los datos sensibles a los repositorios, puedes manejarlos por variables de entorno del sistema, normalmente asociadas a un archivo `.env`

Comment: la idea es que configures un config o las variables de entorno del servidor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo combino 3 cosas el .gitignore, creo un config.py, modifico el manage.py, documento como configurar el config.py

En el .gitignore agrego el archivo config.py

```
# Configuraciones
proyecto/config.py
```

**config.py**

```
from .settings import * #no olvidar agregar esto

#https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.2/
BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:8000'

#SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

#https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE'   : 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'HOST'     : 'localhost',
        'NAME'     : 'base',
        'USER'     : 'usuario',
        'PASSWORD' : '123',
    }
}


#Mail is sent using the SMTP host and port specified in the
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.tuserver.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'tumail@tudominio.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'tupass'
```

**Modifico el manage.py lo apunto al cofig.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

**Documento como configurar el config.py y agrego al README.md un ejemplo del config para q funcione el sistema.**

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar esta libreria [python-dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) es sencillo administrar la configuración de la aplicación tanto en desarrollo como en produccion.

Answer (score 0):

En el `settings.py` nunca se debería de poner datos confidenciales en texto plano.

Normalmente se suele hacer de dos formas, mediante variable de entorno en el servidor o mediante un archivo JSON, siendo éste último el más utilizado.

Para ello te creas tu archivo `config.json` que contenga todos los datos sensibles y lo colocas donde te convenga, yo te recomiendo que sea en una carpeta de configuración dentro de la base del proyecto, por ejemplo:

```
{
    "EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD": "q1w2e3r4t5",
    "DB_PASSWORD": "456dsg91hg5"
}
```

Posteriormente añades en tu `settings.py`:

```
import json
import os
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured

with open(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'config/config.json')) as config_file:
    config = json.load(config_file)

def get_config(setting, config = config ):
    """Obtenemos la configuracion o falla capturando con ImproperlyConfigured"""
    try:
        return config[setting]
    except KeyError:
        raise ImproperlyConfigured("El atributo {} no es correcto".format(setting))
```

Finalmente instancias las variables sensibles:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'mail.domain.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'diego.avila@domain.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = get_config('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
EMAIL_PORT = 465
```